# Creating a list of unevaluated pure functions with Apply

Tags: list-manipulation, map, pure-function

Suppose I have a list `list` with length `L` and a function `listModifier[l_List, n_Integer, m_Integer]` that returns a new list with length `L`. `listModifier` modifies the list in a way dependent on the parameters `(n,m)`.

Furthermore, I possess another array `A={{n3,m3},{n2,m2},{n1,m1}}`, which contain information of the way `list` must be modified in three different steps.

What I am trying to do is something like

```
Apply[listModifier[#3, #1, #2] & , A]
```

in order to construct the new array

```
A2={listModifier[#,n3,m3]&,listModifier[#,n2,m2]&,listModifier[#,n3,m3]&}
```

After which I expect `Composition[A2]` to yield single  function that, when mapped upon the initial state `list` produces the final state of the list reached after the three consecutive modifications.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work out as I can't seem to find a way to create the `A2` array with pure functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then something like this might work for you.

```
A = {{A11, A12}, {A21, A22}, {A31, A32}}
A2 = Function[{l}, listModifier[l, #1, #2]] & @@@ A
A3 = Composition @@ A2
A3[{1, 2, 3}]

(* {{A11, A12}, {A21, A22}, {A31, A32}} *)

(* {Function[{l}, listModifier[l, A11, A12]], 
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, A21, A22]], 
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, A31, A32]]} *)

(* Function[{l}, listModifier[l, A11, A12]]@*
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, A21, A22]]@*
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, A31, A32]] *)

(* listModifier[
 listModifier[listModifier[{1, 2, 3}, A31, A32], A21, A22], A11, A12] *)
```

The trick was to use the `Function` construct as well as the normal slot mechanism (`# /@`) when building up `A2`.

**Edit** I always think better with concrete examples though, so here is one:

```
listModifier[l_List, n_Integer, m_Integer] := n/m + # & /@ l
A = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {3, 2}]
A2 = Function[{l}, listModifier[l, #1, #2]] & @@@ A
A3 = Composition @@ A2
A3[{1, 2, 3}]

(* {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {6, 8}} *)

(* {Function[{l}, listModifier[l, 1, 4]], 
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, 2, 6]], 
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, 6, 8]]} *)

(* Function[{l}, listModifier[l, 1, 4]]@*
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, 2, 6]]@*
 Function[{l}, listModifier[l, 6, 8]] *)

(* {7/3, 10/3, 13/3} *)
```